# Z3 Solver Z3_parse_smtlib2_file - Z3 C API push pop

Tags: z3

How to use (push) and (pop) while reading benchmark using Z3_parse_smtlib2_file API. How can I get result for (assert(not(= o2_s o2_i ))) and (assert(not(= o1_s o1_i ))) constraints using Z3_parse_smtlib2_file API. I am getting result for (assert(not(= o1_s o1_i ))) only while reading benchmark using Z3_parse_smtlib2_file API in C.

```
(declare-fun i_s () Int)
(declare-fun t_s () Int)
(declare-fun o1_s () Int)
(declare-fun o2_s () Int)
(declare-fun i_i () Int)
(declare-fun t_i () Int)
(declare-fun o1_i () Int)
(declare-fun o2_i () Int)

(assert(= i_s 10) )
(assert(>= (+ (- 5) (* 1 i_s)) 0))
(assert(= t_s (+ 1 (* 1 i_s))) )
(assert(< (+ (- 20) (* 1 t_s)) 0))
(assert(= o1_s (+ 1 (* 1 t_s))) )
(assert(= o2_s (+ 0 (* 1 t_s))) )

(assert(= i_i 10) )
(assert(>= (+ (- 5) (* 1 i_i)) 0))
(assert(= t_i (+ 2 (* 1 i_i))) )
(assert(< (+ (- 21) (* 1 t_i)) 0))
(assert(= o1_i (+ 0 (* 1 t_i))) )
(assert(= o2_i (+ 0 (* 1 t_i))) )

(push)

(assert(not(= o2_s o2_i )))
(pop)
(assert(not(= o1_s o1_i )))
```

Comment: Once you pop something from the formula stack, it is gone. If it is possible to parse multiple files into the same context incrementally, then you should split your file in 3: a `common` file part, a `1st push` part and a `2nd push` part; then parse the `common` part, manually push, parse the `1st push` part, check for satisfiability, manually pop + manually push,  parse the `2nd push` part, check for satisfiability, manually pop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported. `Z3_parse_smtlib2_file` extracts only the assertions from the file and ignores most other SMT2 commands. Z3 does not currently support extraction of a set of SMT2 commands that can be modified later.